# Download wait time

Tags: web, download

Most websites adds a 20 to 30 seconds timer to start a download automatically, and a link to start it immediately.

What is the benefit of that? from user point of view, and from site owner point of view.

Is it for advertising purposes only, or there is a technical side for this waiting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most sites keep a counter on downloads. On the other hand, it can also be related to poorly written code. However, for monetary purposes - This is often done to push people to purchase a subscription for "faster" downloads and NO wait times.

Several movie sites do it as well as hosting sites that offer user uploaded content.

For owners this is sometimes lucrative depending on their traffic.

For users, it's bothersome to wait and usually, unless the content is hard to find, go elsewhere or just leave and come back after download is done.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I had this question in mind when I was trying to download Framework from Microsoft, they had no Adds, but still, a waiting timer is used there